# Migration spring-boot from 2.1.8.RELEASE to 2.7.7- keeping spring-fox dependencies

Tags: swagger, jhipster, swagger-ui

I migrated a jhipster application generated with jhipster version 6.3.0.

Everything is right except swagger. I don't want for now to migrate to springdoc. I just kept springfox.

I get this exception when go to `/admin/docs`:

```
Refused to frame 'http://swagger.io/' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-src 'self' data:".
```

Should I change the CSP or something else ?

Right now I have this line in `SecurityConfiguration`

```
 .contentSecurityPolicy("default-src 'self'; frame-src 'self' data:; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://storage.googleapis.com https://www.googletagmanager.com https://www.google-analytics.com; style-src 'self' https://fonts.googleapis.com 'unsafe-inline'; img-src 'self' www.googletagmanager.com https://www.google-analytics.com data:; font-src 'self' https://fonts.gstatic.com data:")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem of CSP by using:
`.and().frameOptions().sameOrigin()`.
But finally I had no choices. I was obliged to migrate to springdoc instead.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It should work when adding `http://swagger.io/` to frame-src in the CSP configuration. E.g.

`...; frame-src 'self' http://swagger.io/ data:; ...`